# Why won't the loader load at the desired location

Tags: windows, executable, exe, portable-executable

It is said that sometimes the loader loads the exe at an address which is different than the one assumed by the linker. What all could be the cases when loader does so??

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I was wondering that if it is rare that the loader loads a file at some undesired location then maybe I could use the .reloc section for some other purpose...

Comment: I would not recommend that, no. Win32 PE EXE files are not currently relocated (unlike DLLs), but I wouldn't recommend storing random information in the `.reloc` section just because.

Comment: If you want to add data to your PE, then just add it to the PE the normal way. No need to be sneaky. If you're sneaky, then you may get flagged as malware.

Comment: @CodyGray: EXEs are *too* relocated. That's what ASLR is all about. EXEs that can't be relocated are bad for the security of your system because they can't use the ASLR exploit-mitigation strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this takes place in the following situations:

1. The address at which the image prefers to be loaded is already occupied. For example, there may be another image already loaded there.
2. The image to be loaded has been compiled with [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) enabled.
3. The [`FLG_LDR_TOP_DOWN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779664%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#sectionSection27) global flag has been set, which forces modules to be loaded at the highest possible address.

Comment: FLG_LDR_TOP_DOWN, which is used in the context of the "Global Flags Editor" (aka. GFLAGS.exe) tool, is typically not installed on a customer machine. Additionally, this tool is only for x64 diagnostics.

Comment: The loader will never load an EXE at the wrong address if it it non-ASLRed and non TOP_DOWN because the EXE is the first thing to exist in it's address space (i.e. before even ntdll and the heap). If the EXE has an invalid user-mode address the process won't start in this case, so the EXE will always get it's favourite address subject to not liking ASLR and not using TOP_DOWN.