# What does MapViewOfFile return?

Tags: windows, winapi, exe, portable-executable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why won't the loader load at the desired location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698496/why-wont-the-loader-load-at-the-desired-location)

"MapViewOfFile", does this function map a file into the virtual memory and return the base address of the mapped memory?? If yes, then the following code should output 0X400000, beacuse by default, exe's are loaded at this location, but the output is 0X360000. Why??

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<WinNT.h>


int main()
{


HANDLE  hFile,hFileMapping;
LPVOID lpFileBase;


if((hFile = CreateFile(TEXT("c:\\linked list.exe"),GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    std::cout<<"unable to open";

if((hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile,NULL,PAGE_READONLY,0,0,NULL)) == 0)
{
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    std::cout<<"unable to open for mapping";
}

if((lpFileBase = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping,FILE_MAP_READ,0,0,0))== 0)
{
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    std::cout<<"couldn't map view of file";
}

printf("%x\n",lpFileBase);

}
```

Comment: Yes, the *code you wrote* is mapped at 0x400000 (ignoring ASLR).  Not the file you load later, it can't be mapped to that address because it is already taken by your code.  Linker, Advanced, Base Address option to move your code elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The 0X400000 you researched has nothing to do with normal file mapping.

You can *imagine* MapViewOfFile as a malloc+memcpy of the file you are opening, nothing more (under the hood it is the reverse: malloc can use a slab'ed memory mapping). So MapViewOfFile normally just chooses an address where it can fit the file view's bytes continuously in memory.

What you probably want (since you are trying to map an .exe) is to create a new Process with it [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you really need the file to be mapped at a specific address you can use [MapViewOfFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but there are no guarantees.

Comment: Well actually I don't want to map the file into the main memory, I just want to work on the copy of the file on the disk, but most of the addresses in the PE headers are RVA's, and I don't know how to convert an RVA to a file offset...

Comment: The RVA's **are** the offset within the file so there is no conversion you have to do. Only when Windows loads an exe for you it converts RVA's to heap-addresses.

Comment: I guess you are already reading this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx because it simply is the best resource on the topic. Depending on your needs you could also have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680218%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Well actually I am reading this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ms809762.aspx

Comment: I need to know how to convert an RVA into a file offset, the article you suggested (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680218%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) converts an RVA to VA..

Comment: I believe a function to do the reverse is not amongst the DbgHelp functions because DbgHelp functions always operate on loaded modules. But since you are working on the file itself there is no need even to reverse the RVA translation because it has not happened: the RVA *is* the offset within the file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MapViewOfFile returns the virtual memory base address where the image has been loaded. The value (content) of this address depends on whether the image has been successfully loaded at its predefined address (which has been setup by the linker) or whether the image has been relocated (because the desired, predefined address is already occupied or because the image has opt-in to support [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)).

Answer (score 0):

To convert an RVA into a file offset, find a delta and use that. I assume you're trying to do something like look at where an RVA in the dataDirectory structure of a PE file points to, after memory-mapping the PE file? Look at the IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER struct:

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER {  
BYTE    Name[IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME];  
union {  
          DWORD   PhysicalAddress;  
          DWORD   VirtualSize;  
  } Misc;  
  DWORD   VirtualAddress;  
  DWORD   SizeOfRawData;  
  DWORD   PointerToRawData;  
  DWORD   PointerToRelocations;  
  DWORD   PointerToLinenumbers;  
  WORD    NumberOfRelocations;  
  WORD    NumberOfLinenumbers;  
  DWORD   Characteristics;  
} IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER, *PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER;
```

You'll want to make a delta by finding the difference in the section's VirtualAddress and PointerToRawData value. Then, for an RVA into a given section, subract off the delta to get the file offset.

In my experience this is different for each section. So if you have an RVA into the second section listed in the section table, the delta will be different from the second section listed in the section table. For this it helps to have a function to determine what section an RVA points into. And you should edit your question to show that this is the question you're asking.