# Image of a file

Tags: winapi, memory-management, paging, virtual-memory

What does Image of a file mean when we say something like "the system allocates enough storage from the paging file to hold the file's image"?

Comment: I think the two answers too narrowly focus on executables.  The type of the file is irrelevant.  A "file's image" is simply a copy of that file.  It might be in memory or in a page file, but no matter where it is, it's still just a copy of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The image of a file is typically the content of a file that is executable. Before being able to execute an application (EXE, ...but also DLL, SYS..) the Loader copy the appropriate executable parts (which are contained in a file on a medium) to the memory (mapping). Once successfully done, the loader jump to the entry point (in memory) and runs the program.

Comment: This is the "standard" ways of things (99 % of the executables are started from a file). Sometimes, executables are not located in files, but are directly started from memory, but that is another story.

Comment: Does mapping means simply copying the contents of a file from disk to memory?

Comment: Mapping is a mechanism which the Memory manager uses to make virtual memory areas visible. When mapping takes place, the content of the file is already in memory (hence the name MapViewOfFile - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718616/what-does-mapviewoffile-return)

Answer (score 0):

If this is, what I think it is, you are talking about `DLL`s and similar beasts: Code, that is loaded into a running process.

In this case, the whole DLL is mapped into (virtual) memory and then this memeory is marked as executable. The need to do this stems from the fact, that typically code can not be run from Disk, but need to be run from Memory.

Comment: Code is never run from disk. Code must always be first mapped into Memory (hence mapping) and then the code can be run.

Comment: Which is what I said! The word "typically" relates to (old) architectures, where this in fact was possible - see http://www.pbm.com/~lindahl/mel.html

Comment: Windows does not do that, and this was the question ..."the system allocates enough storage from the paging file to hold the file's image.

Comment: Yup. This is why I wrote "**typically** code can not be run from Disk"